# Adding a Birthday to my Employee class java

Tags: java, calendar

I'm sure at some point when you are first learning programming we create some kind of program that teaches us interfaces, abstracts, and polymorphism. Well, that's what I'm trying to do right now.

I'm coding in Java, and I'm trying to create an Abstract employee class. I'm running in to one little problem with it though. I want to add a birthday to the Employee, but I'm not sure how to do that with calendar.

I would like to be able to store the Birthday like I would the employees name i.e.  `public String employeeName;`. Creating it as a variable would allow me to use getters and setters on it.

The employee Constructor would look something like this:

```
public Employee(String name, int idNumber, String Gender, 
    int year, int month, int day)
```

To sum up how to I create a birthday variable using a calendar, and if I wanted to get the birthday date(whatever it is set to) how would I do that? thank you.

Comment: I don't think that you should create an arbitrarily long amount of arguments in a constructor. You had better use a `Calendar` instance, and copy that information because `Calendar` instances are mutable. Note that not everybody's birthday is known.

Comment: I thought about doing something like that, but i wasn't sure it was correct. i have something like this `public Employee(String Name, int IDNumber, String Gender, int Month, int Day, int Year)
 {
  
  this.employeeName  = Name;
  this.idNumber = IDNumber;
  this.gender = Gender;
  calendar.set(Year, Month, Day);
 }` but how would i return the date stored?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is a way to go:

```
// declare  birthday as Date:

private Date birthday;

public Employee(String name, int idNumber, String gender, 
    int year, int month, int day) {

    this.name  = name;
    this.idNumber = idNumber;
    this.gender = gender;
    initBirthday(year, month, day);
}

private void initBirthday(int year, int month, int day) {
    // all int should be greater than 0 
    if (year > 0 && month > 0 && day > 0) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(year, month-1 , day, 0, 0, 0);
// OR the explicit way 
 //           cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
 //           cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1); // january == 0 !!!!
 //           cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
 //           cal.set(Calendar.HOUR,0);
 //           cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
 //           cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
            birthday = cal.getTime(); // this returns a Date
    } else {
       // set birthday to a default value...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having 3 different variables you should use java.util.Date (deprecated) or java.util.Calendar.

Comment: @Jadex1 you can but you shouldn't, it may be removed from later versions of Java, although removing Date would deprecate a lot of programs. `Date` however is not deprecated, you can store a `Date`, but currently you should use one of the `Calendar` classes to create a date (different than the current date/time).

Answer (score -1):

Private Date birthdayDate ... getter would be just Return birtdayDay OR private Calendar birthDate and getter would be retirn birthdayDate.getDate()

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). So your `Employee` class will look like this:

```
public class Employee {
  private Date Birthday;
  public Employe(Date birthday) {}
}
```

This is the idea.

Answer (score -2):

Java provides the Date class available in java.util package, this class encapsulates the current date and time.

Also pass parameter of Date Of Birth in the constructor of Employee:

```
import java.util.*;


public Employee(String name, int idNumber, String Gender, 
    int year, int month, int day, Date dob)
```